Complete Application Deployment using CloudFormation AWS
I'm using CloudFormation in AWS to create the infrastructure and deploy the application.  My Infra contains EKS Cluster with NodeGroups and ALB. I have manifest files in S3.
Is CloudFormation is only to create the Architecture?
It is possible to deploy the complete application using CloudFormation? If No, Do we have any documentation for this ?
